# Why is it so diffuclt to update by association in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have two models that are associated via hasMany on the source Model.
It took a while as it was my first time using Sequelize, but I have been able to create a new user and get the list of users in the database using the include parameter.
But when I try to use include an update, it does update the source Model, but not the information on the associated model

Model 1

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import database from "../index";
import PlayerSkill from "./playerSkill";

const Player = database.define(
    "player",
    {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(200),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        position: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(200),
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: false,
    }
);

Player.hasMany(PlayerSkill, {
    // through: "players_skills",
    as: "playerSkills",
    timestamps: false,
    foreignKey: false,
    // attributes: { exclude: ["playerSkillId"] },
});

// Player.hasMany(PlayerSkill);
// PlayerSkill.belongsTo(Player);

export default Player;
```

Model 2

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import database from "../index";

const PlayerSkill = database.define(
    "playerSkill",
    {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        skill: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(200),
        },
        value: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: false,
    }
);

export default PlayerSkill;
```

**Create Route works fine**

```
   import Player from "../../db/model/player";
    import PlayerSkill from "../../db/model/playerSkill";
    
    export default async (req, res) => {
        const { name, position, playerSkills } = req.body;
        try {
            const player = await Player.create(
                {
                    name,
                    position,
                    playerSkills,
                },
                {
                    include: "playerSkills",
                }
            );
            console.log(`Player created and saved!`);
            res.json(player);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.stack);
        }
    };



import Player from "../../db/model/player";

export default async (req, res) => {
    const requestedId = req.params.id;
    try {
        const { name, position, playerSkills } = req.body;
        const player = await Player.update(
            {
                name,
                position,
                playerSkills,
            },
            {
                include: "playerSkills",
                where: { id: requestedId },
            }
        );
        res.json(player);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(` This is the error ${error}`);
    }
};
```

**Update will only update the Player table**

```
import Player from "../../db/model/player";

export default async (req, res) => {
    const requestedId = req.params.id;
    try {
        const { name, position, playerSkills } = req.body;
        const player = await Player.update(
            {
                name,
                position,
                playerSkills,
            },
            {
                include: "playerSkills",
                where: { id: requestedId },
            }
        );
        res.json(player);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(` This is the error ${error}`);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The model's `update` method does not support `include` option, so you either need to use generated helper methods in the main model to add/change/delete associated items or use direct methods of the associated model to do that.